# How can i show that $\frac{k^3}{3^k}$ is monotonic decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

How can i show that $\frac{k^3}{3^k}$ is monotonic decreasing I know its for $3\leq k$ so i try by induction starting for $k=3$ but i having trouble to show is valid for $k+1$

Answer (score 2):

If $\dfrac{k^3}{3^k}$ is monotonic decreasing then $$\frac{k^3}{3^k}-\frac{(k+1)^3}{3^{k+1}}>0\\
 \impliedby 
3k^3-(k+1)^3>0 \\\impliedby 
3k^3-k^3-3k^2-3k-1>0 \\\impliedby 
2k^3-3k^2-3k-1>0$$ It can be trivially shown that $2k^3-3k^2-3k-1>0$ for all $k>3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_k \equiv \frac{k^3}{3^k}$.

$a_{k+1}/a_{k} < 1$  $\iff$ $ \frac{1}{3}(1+\frac{1}{n})^3 <1$ $\iff n>2.2614$